# C++/Linux Aligning an array of chars for performance reasons?

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, memory-alignment

I am writing some code on Linux, in C++ where I create a large char array for byte processing. After doing some reading I was wondering whether I should align the array on a 16 byte boundary, apparently this can allow the CPU to take advantage of SSE?

If so, how can I tell the GCC compiler where I wish the array to be aligned?

Comment: The simplest solution is just to call `malloc`, which will return a pointer to an aligned block of memory.

Comment: You first should write clean and reusuable code. Unless you have some mission critical application, I wouldn't worry about this array.

Comment: Please further describe what you are trying to accomplish, maybe with some code.

Comment: Some people seem to mix up downvoting and answering "no"...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, does `malloc` ensure to return a pointer of 16B alignment? I didn't find out that in its man page but got that it only ensure to align for built-in types.

Comment: @Quentin, I think this question is resonalbe. I don't know why some people voted down.

Comment: @nicky_zs The `malloc` function returns a pointer that meets the highest alignment requirements of any type supported by the platform.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, `malloc` can ensure 8-byte alignment in a 64-bit system but some SSE instructions require 16-byte alignment.

Comment: (+1) Good question. I had seen similar questions several times. In programming theory should not matter, in real world practice, aligment does matter.

Answer (score 1):

Memory alignment doesn't directly cause GCC to generate SSE code. If you really want GCC to generate SSE code, you should use at least one of the following:

1. [GCC Optimize Options](http://www.manpages.info/linux/gcc.1.html) like `-msse`, `-mtune`.
2. Assembly, or [Inline Assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C)
3. [GCC Vector Extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)

In point 1, whether SSE instructions are generated still depends on the compiler, while in point 2 and 3, SSE instructions are surely to be generated.

Since XMM registers are involved in SSE, a lot of SSE instructions do require strict memory alignment for 128-bit. You can use [GCC Type Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) `__attribute__ ((aligned (N)))` on your type definition to ensure that.

**NOTE: Memory alignment benefits not only from the potential usage of SSE instructions but also from the usage of atom instructions and efficient cache operations.** In many platforms, an instruction is atomic only when it accesses memory aligned for its size. Meanwhile, cache is usually organized in groups of lines stably mapping to the memory, which needs one more access if the cache line boundary is crossed.

**ALSO NOTE**: `malloc` only ensures to return a pointer which is suitably aligned for any built-in type (see the [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) man page). If you want to align the structs defined by yourself, you should still use the [GCC Type Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) `__attribute__ ((aligned (N)))` mentioned above.

Comment: Not an expert on GCC, but, your answer seems to be more detailed and supported with docs.

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule you should use a vector instead of an array. This would solve also the issue of alignement.

Comment: (-1) @Emanuele Paolini. Disagree, in critical applications, memory managment is important. I like STL vectors for a lot of functuonality, but, in many cases, arrays are better ar performance. Just my 2 cents.